# Unable to install capybara-webkit even though qt is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qt, command-line, ubuntu-14.04, capybara-webkit

I want to install [`gem capybara-webkit`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)  but when I run `bundle install`, I get the following errors:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/dineshp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160814-4696-3d7ixk.rb extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/dineshp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-gl-dir
--without-gl-dir
--with-gl-include
--without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
--with-gl-lib
--without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/dineshp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails420/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/dineshp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails420/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.11.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.11.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

As the above error shows: **Command 'qmake ' not available**, I tried installing `qt` using the following command after referring [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#ubuntu-trusty-1404%0A):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev
```

When I type `qmake --version`, I get the following message:

```
The program 'qmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install qtchooser
```

As I know I have installed qt, I tried running the `qtchooser -list-versions` and I get the following list of qt versions in my system:

```
4
5
default
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

Why I am not able to access **`qmake`** commands from terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

`qtchooser` lets you select the default version of Qt to have accessible in your path. You haven't made that choice yet. Not only you have to install `qtchooser`, you also have to use it to make the selection.

Comment: thanks for the response :)... I did `export QT_SELECT=qt5` and then checked `qtchooser -print-env`, I got result as: `QT_SELECT="qt5"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"`   - then again I tried `qmake -v` but I got `The program 'qmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install qtchooser`

Comment: @dkp I don't think that's how it works. If `qt_chooser` is anything like `port --select` on BSD, then you have to do something like `qt_chooser qt5` for it to generate symbolic links. If that fails, then you need to invoke the right qmake manually, or add it to the path in your `.bash_profile`.